# how to create editable dropdown in android?

Tags: android, spinner

Can anyone help me with how to make an editable dropdown in android?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If editable you should use [AutoCompleteTextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html).

Comment: Diego, URL not found!

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem too. I finally tried 2 means:

1. Use [AutoCompleTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html), it is pretty good.
2. Use [`ListPopupWindow`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html) with a `EditText`. I finally used this and I wrote an article about it: http://maogm.com/blog/edittext-with-popuplist-en.html

Comment: The link for article (Edittext with popouplist) wasn't found!

Comment: @LeonardoCosta I've update the link

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer helped me except I wanted the drop down to show immediately before the user starts typing (really an editable spinner) and didn't care much about auto completetion, so I let it have the immediate drop down effect by adding:

```
autoCompleteTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                autoCompleteTextView.showDropDown();
            }
        })
```

In case this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reading any tutorials?

For example:
http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html
http://www.designerandroid.com/?p=8

and so forth. Google for android spinner tutorials.

Answer (score -1):

I changed the `ArrayAdapter` method of spinner and i got my custom Spinner. just change the parameter of this method like

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);
ArrayAdapter adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(This,R.array.statename,R.layout.mylayout);
spinner.setAdapter(adp);
```

In Which the mylayout file contains